# Cant install rails on my brand new Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

Just got a new macbook pro and im having troubles installing rails..
I got ruby 1.8.7 already installed and when i try to write 'gem install rails' i get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I also tried to install a higher version of ruby and it said:

```
    Nirs-MacBook-Pro:~ nirohayon$ rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix="/Users/nirohayon/.rvm/usr"  ', please read /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/make.log


Database file /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/nirohayon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/nirohayon/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
ls: /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/rubies/*/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

PLEASE help me, i used windows before and also pretty new to rails, so i dont know much about which path should i direct my terminal. i need a step by step explanation to put rails up and standing on my mac.

Thanks so much!
Nir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of RVM looks a lot like you don't have the developer tools installed. Grab XCode from the App Store, the install the command line tools!

If you really want to install rails on the platform-provided ruby, all you need to do is to `sudo gem install rails`, for you need to use administrator privileges to isntall gems in the system gemset.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get to the command line tool installation? i already downloaded xcode.

Comment: In XCode's preferences, go in the "Downloads" section, then "Components", pick "Command Line Tools" and click "Install".

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: Oh right. XCode 4.3 uses Clang, doesn't work with Ruby <= 1.9.2 (before whatever patchlevel fixed it). I recommend trying on your RVM ruby 1.9.x - I mean, there are other questions here dealing with this specific issue.

Comment: after i installed the command line tools the ruby 1.9.3 installation went properly! tnx allot :)

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) helped me install on mac before with OS X 10.6 (I believe). The only thing that was a trouble was the C compiler, which I figured out was the problem from looking up one of the errors.

Probably you will find by looking up the output `Error running 'make ', please read /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/make.log` by typing `vi /Users/nirohayon/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/yaml/make.log` type `esc` key followed by typing `:q!` to quit.

As previous answer suggested, you need to get a compiler. I don't know about Xcode specifics, but I tracked down an installer for GCC compiler for Mac on Github I believe but it is probably better straight from Apple packages, ([tutorial here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/726/mac-os-x-install-gcc-compiler/))

Also note that if you end up having to use `sudo` at all, you've probably gone off-track from the guide to install RVM on your system. In which case your path will be somewhere other than in the home directory and the instruction to adjust your source with `echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bash_profile` will not work. Which may end up being somewhere like `"/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: Yep, looks like sudo was used when installing rvm.